# How to find the largest circle that fits inside a simple planar polygon?

Tags: geometry, optimization, circles, computational-geometry

Given a 2D simple polygon with $n$ vertices, how would I find the largest circle (whose centre and radius are unknown) that fits inside (circle can be tangent to edges/coincident with vertices) the polygon? Is there any way to solve this analytically as opposed to algorithmically?

Comment: If by polygon you mean a regular polygon, then it will be it's in-circle.

Comment: @John Does regular imply that the polygon is 'convex'? If so, no...I deal with arbitrary polygons too.

Comment: @John Oh right, I just read the definition of regular. No, the polygon could have arbitrary lengths.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279478/largest-circle-inside-a-non-convex-polygon might be worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could mix analytic and algorithmic. The maximiser circle will necessarily be constrained by three conditions which could be either "containing a vertex"  or "being tangent to one of the edges". So you could iterate over each of the $\binom {2n} 3$ possible sets of three constraints, translate those into systems of equations, and solve them, throw out solutions that are not actually inscribed, and then maximise radius...

Comment: It might also help to note that a vertex can be contained only when its internal angle exceeds $180^\circ$.

Comment: @URL Good point!